# Align word to the right after Equation (same line)

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'm trying to get a name for the equation (AA) in the same line. Unfortunately it appears one line below.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% 
 \begin{eqnarray*}
 x  & \geq & y+z \\
 \Leftrightarrow x -z & \geq & y  \end{eqnarray*}  \hfill (AA)
 %
```

But I want the AA to occur in the same line as the last equation. Can someone tell me how to get this result? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use `eqnarray`](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf). Use the `align` environment from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), and use the `\tag` command for the custom label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}   
 x  & \geq  y+z \nonumber \\ 
 \Leftrightarrow x -z & \geq  y \tag{AA}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]